# Floating Action Button not moving up and down

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

**Problem:** I have implemented a `FloatingActionButton` and I followed the sample of Androidhive. But when the `SnackBar` is shown the `FloatingActionButton` does not move up.

**Question:** How can I achieve that the `FloatingActionButton` will move up and down if the `SnackBar` appears?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/maschineCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/maschinelistcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
       />

    <com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle
        android:id="@+id/fabProgressCircle_download_maschinen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_download_maschinen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is FloatingAction Behaviour class

**FloatingActionButtonBehavior.java**

```
public class FloatingActionButtonBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {

  public FloatingActionButtonBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof SnackbarLayout;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
    float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
    child.setTranslationY(translationY);
    return true;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Hello Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.getbase.coordinatorlayoutdemo.FloatingActionButtonBehavior"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Output :**

[image]

For More detail visit this : https://github.com/ggajews/coordinatorlayoutwithfabdemo

Comment: I have added your suggestions to my code. Unfortunately the button still does not want to move. Is it possible that the FABProgressCircle is the problem here?

Comment: did you require the progress or not ?

Comment: yes, I need to progress Indicator. Is it possible to implement the moving behavior to it?

Comment: @jublikon using this library that can not possible ?

Comment: if there is no other possibility I would do it like that. But the progress indicator gives a intuitive design

Answer (score 0):

I am using com.android.support:design:24.2.0 and for that to work you need to put yor FAB inside a CoordinatorLayout, I don't know if you can wrap as are you doing.
Then write in your FAB:

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/maschinelistcontainer"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

Like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_download_maschinen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/maschinelistcontainer"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"     />
```

For more details: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220250

Answer (score -1):

i think you did implement the `FABProgressListener` interface

if not.you have do that.

you should use snackbar like below:

```
@Override public void onFABProgressAnimationEnd() {
    Snackbar.make(fabProgressCircle, R.string.cloud_upload_complete, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Action", null)
        .show();
}
```

did you reed [this page](https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/FABProgressCircle)?

Comment: Can you explain why it is needed, please? Unfortunately the button does not move even if the progres indicator is not shown

Comment: i reed in [this page](https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/FABProgressCircle) told when you implement the FABProgressListener interface you should use snackbar like that example code. because the following method call will be dispatched at the right time